# Finding derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So I was practicing calculus and stumbled upon a derivative which I am having a difficulty completing:
The question asks me for the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

$\tan (y) = (x-y)^2$

so here are the steps I made:

$\frac{d}{dx}  \tan(y) = \frac{d}{dx} (x-y)^2$

$\sec^2(y) \frac{dy}{dx} = -2(x-y) \frac{dy}{dx}$

And here is where I stop:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2(x-y)}{\sec^2(y)} \frac{dy}{dx}$

Anyhow, 
any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: When differentiating $(x-y)^2$ I get
$$2\left(1-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)(x-y).$$

Comment: When you take the derivative of the right side, you dropped the derivative of $x$.  It should be $2(x-y)(1-\frac{dy}{dx}).$  Multiply it out.  Put all the $dy/dx$ terms on one side and factor it out.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is an implicit differentiation problem.  If so, you have an error:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (x - y(x))^2 = 2 (x - y(x)) \frac{d}{dx} (x - y(x)) = 2 (x - y(x)) \left( 1 - \frac{dy}{dx} \right) \neq -2 (x - y(x)) \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)
$$
You can then rearrange the resulting equation to solve for $dy/dx$.